# cannot add data to local DB sqlite IOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

Here is my code:

For creating the DB, in my ViewDidLoad:

```
 NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    dirPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"contacts.db"]];

    NSFileManager *filemgr=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]==NO)
    {
        NSLog(@"Creating DB");
        const char *dbpath=[databasePath UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB)==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            char *error_msg;
            const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, URL TEXT, EMAIL TEXT, CODE TEXT, FULL TEXT)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error_msg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
               NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
            }

            sqlite3_close(contactDB);

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"DB exists");
    }
```

I can see the output message `"Creating DB"`

Then where I have to add my data there I do have:

```
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

                const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

                if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
                {
                    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (url, email, code, full) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", url_2, mail, keycode,full_2 ];

                    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

                    sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
                    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
                    {
                        NSLog(@"Contact added");
                    } else {
                        NSLog(@"Failed to add contact");
                    }
                    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
                    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
                } else {
                    NSLog(@"PROBLEM - CONTACT NOT ADDED");
                }
```

and I see the `"PROBLEM - CONTACT NOT ADDED"` message.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you made a minor mistake as shown by @Rob...

Instead of

`dirPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);`

you should use

`dirPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);`

Following is the corrected code,

```
NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;

dirPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"contacts.db"]];

NSFileManager *filemgr=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]==NO)
{
    NSLog(@"Creating Database...");
    const char *dbpath=[databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *error_msg;
        const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, URL TEXT, EMAIL TEXT, CODE TEXT, FULL TEXT)";

        if (sqlite3_exec(contactDB, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &error_msg) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
           NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
        }

        sqlite3_close(contactDB);

    } 
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
    }
} 
else 
{
    NSLog(@"DB exists");
}
```

You can insert data like this,

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (url, email, code, full) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", url_2, mail, keycode,full_2 ];

    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"Contact added");
    } 
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Failed to add contact");
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
} 
else
{
    NSLog(@"PROBLEM - CONTACT NOT ADDED");
}
```

Thank You...!!!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're opening your database in the `NSDocumentationDirectory`, not the `NSDocumentDirectory`.

A couple of unrelated observations:

1. If `sqlite3_open()` fails, you should look at the numeric return code which will help you diagnose the source of the problem. You can look up the values in the `sqlite3.h` header file.
2. An unrelated observation to your code sample: You should check your `sqlite3_prepare_v2()` return code as SQL errors are generally identified there, not at `sqlite3_step()`. If it returned something other than `SQLITE_OK`, then immediately call `sqlite3_errmsg()` to identify precisely why it failed.
3. You should not use `stringWithFormat` to add values for `INSERT` SQL  statement. Instead, use `?` placeholders and then use [`sqlite3_bind_XXX()`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) functions to bind values to those SQL values. As it is, if any of your inserted values contained a quotation mark, your SQL would fail (and would be susceptible to SQL injection attacks).